# How do I get dividends that I am owed for physical stock share certificates I hold?

Tags: united-kingdom, dividends

My Mum has held shares in Carnival for 30 years. She has a certificate for shares worth a lot of money. Over the years she moved address and lost touch with the company. She must have accumulated many dividends but where are they? Who will hold them & how does she find out how much they are worth?

Comment: Does she still have the certificate? You mentioned she lost touch with the company; is it a publicly traded company? (i.e. one listed on a securities market such as the London Stock Exchange)?

Comment: Yes she has the certificate and I checked the value of the shares on LSE... the company is Carnival and they have issued lots of dividends but she doesnt seem to have received any...perhaps sent to the wrong address

Comment: It's not an answer to your question but just a thought: maybe it would suit to hold the shares with an online stockbroker platform, instead of paper certificates. That way dividends are collected automatically for you, and can be paid out to your bank, or reinvested. They can also be sold easily when the time comes. Hargreaves Lansdown can transfer in paper certificates: see http://www.hl.co.uk/investment-services/fund-and-share-account/transfer-existing-funds-and-shares Also for better tax treatment (no CGT / income tax) they could be held in an ISA.

Answer (score 8):

I think the first step is to contact [Carnival Investor Relations](http://phx.corporate-ir.net/phoenix.zhtml?c=140690&p=irol-irhome). They can give you information about what attempts they have made to pay dividends since the address has changed. There may be some hoops that you have to jump through to get the funds, but the simple answer is to call them and find out.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you taking the time to answer; I will try that and let you know how it goes; cheers for now, JJ

Comment: Yes, please report back and let us know what happens! I'm quite curious myself, great question.